# Error on creating named pipe: error code -1

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I am working on macOS 10.15.3

```
      try{
        var pipee = new NamedPipeClientStream("../../../../../../PIPE/myfifo1");
        pipee.Connect();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipee);
        Debug.Log("AYEMAN"+reader.ReadLine());
      }
      catch(IOException e){
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
      }
```

this is the code I tried to implement for a pipe in C# which is trying to read a named pipe created by a C++ program in a different folder. It keeps giving me error code -1. Before I put the code in try catch, it was throwing IOException.

Comment: Format for a Windows named pipe path is `\\<pc name>\pipe\<pipe name>` See the [`NamedPipeClientStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1) constructor for more options. If the pipe server is on the same pc, you can just use `var pipee = new NamedPipeClientStream("myfifo1");`

Comment: _I am working on macOS 10.15.3_ Ah, well I'm not a Mac guy. Try out my suggestion anyway - pass just the pipe name `"myfifo1"` to the constructor without the path stuff.

Comment: If you're connecting to the server counterpart in the local machine, `var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "myfifo1", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation);` then `await client.ConnectAsync([CancellationToken]);`. I'm not sure whether the impersonation can work in your context: if it doesn't, use a constructor that creates default values. The `PipeDirection` setting depends on what the server is set to.